# iOS app going to background after launch

Tags: ios, background, launch

My problem is as follow

**When I launch app, launch image appears for few seconds and apps goes to background. I faced this problem after updating to iOS 9.2.1**

For solving this problem I delete my app and reinstall it, then it works perfectly fine but lost all important data, so this is not the suitable solution.

I search for the possible solution but unable to find any help, so please help me to solve this problem.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gzdkm3tq4qfnovq/appcrash.mov?dl=0

This happen to app when I launch

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure it's going to the background and not actually crashing?

Comment: Yes I am sure, it is visible with all background apps

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: app is crashing, look for crash report

Comment: means when you tapped home button 2 times, the screen display all applications which is currently running, it is visible there

Comment: @raki, no it is not crashing, because same problem is with other app also

Comment: It seems you don't understand what the "recently used apps list" is for. Your app is crashing. Crashed apps still appear in the "recently used apps list". It doesn't mean the app is in the background.

Comment: @Indrajeet I am having the same issue in my app. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @HassanAftab I solved it by reinstalling app

Comment: Apparantly my issue was that: I was performing too much operations in AppDelegate. App was taking too much time and OS was killing the app before proper launching. I solved this issue by optimizing the code

Comment: i had the same problem but doing nothing in app delegate no heavy  operation

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Right after I open the app it disappears and goes to background. Even if I click on it, it still does not remain visible.

Comment: I am seeing the same same thing sporadically, logging shows applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidEnterBackground, but app remains visible.  Hitting home button puts it into proper background, and then it is fine when brought back to foreground.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any application security software like iXguard? I had faced a similar silent crash and it was due to iXguard obfuscating UIKit call sometime.

One way to resolve this is to add UIKit in the blacklist array.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary for you to manually add SDK frameworks to the blacklist, iXGuard should take care of this automatically. Feel free to send us a support ticket regarding this!